# Export SQL Database for local use Java

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, local-database

I'm working on a desktop Java app that requires a local database (server isn't an option). Every install of the application should come with the database. I'm using SQL Developer but don't how to 'export' the database (not the schema)? Is that even possible?

If the application has to create the database upon install, what would the connection string look like (in particular, the user and password fields)?

My current set up has a user that I made and a link from IntelliJ to the database, but I'm not sure this will work elsewhere since the user won't exist.

Thanks!

Comment: A full Oracle installation seems likely to be overkill for a desktop application to store local data. And possibly expensive depending on version/edition and licencing. How much, and what kind of, data are you expecting to store? There might be other more appropriate options.

Comment: SQL Developer is not a database - it is an IDE use to access database(s).

Comment: @AlexPoole not much data, user profile and user activity. The client mustn't need to install any external software (other than Java).

Comment: @MT0 OK, how do I export the database from there though? I can export schema but is it possible to build the database from Java with that then?

Comment: It is not possible to export an Oracle database application - you could install the database in a virtual machine and distribute that (paying very close attention to Oracle's license conditions) with your Java program but your users would also need to install the VM software and the VM.

Comment: @MT0 I see, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [H2 Data Base](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)
 to set up an in memory data base and it is closed once the application closes. You need to store the application data in the client machine upon closing the application and load it back on startup.

Here is a good place to get started with [H2 Database with Spring](https://www.javatips.net/blog/h2-in-memory-database-example).

Comment: Indeed, and H2 can run in MySQL mode, so no changes to existing MySQL typical SQL needs to be made. One can run the database in every possible way, also **file based, persistently**. Upvoted the downvote.

Comment: Don't really think this is what I'm after. The point of the database is to keep data persistent. If I have to save it separately, the entire point of the database is voided. It is also preferred to use SQL Developer or SQLite at worst.

Comment: @littleCoder.. it is perfectly fine to use H2 Database for java desktop application. You can run H2 in sql mode. Otherwise you can place the data in a file and persist it.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into doing this. Will mark as answer.